# My clutch only engages when it's almost completely out

Tags: clutch, bmw

My 2002 bmw 330xi clutch doesn't engage when it's all the way down. Instead, I have to release it almost all the way up before giving it gas. I'm not sure if it's the clutch or the cylinder.

Comment: Is this new behavior? How many miles on the BMW? Does the clutch slip at all?

Comment: The car has 146,000 miles. This started about a week ago, and the clutch doesn't slip at all.

Comment: I would suggest bleeding the clutch first. If the problem persists, it may be a failed component (i.e. master or slave cylinder) or the clutch itself needs replaced because it is worn out.